# Yii2 REST. How to send post request to actionIndex

Tags: yii2

Yii2, basic template, versioning.
I'm trying to write a method that will give back token.

There is my TokenController:

```
class TokenController extends Controller
{
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new LoginForm();
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->bodyParams, '');
        if ($token = $model->auth()) {
            return $token;
        } else {
            return $model;
        }
    }
}
```

and config:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true, 
            'rules' => [
                ''=>'site/index',
            [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'pluralize' => false, 
                    'controller' => [
                        'v1/token'
                    ],
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'GET <action>'=>'<action>',
                        'POST <action>'=>'<action>',
                    ],

                ],
```

When I send `post` request to `api.site.ru/v1/token` server returns:
[image]

And for an absolutely identical method actionLogin server returns:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `POST` pattern creates a rule to direct to a `create` action. This is why Yii is trying to find a `create` action in your controller. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$patterns-detail) for more details.

I've not tested it, but you should either rename your `index` method to `create`, or override the default patterns like this;

```
'patterns' => [
    'POST'=>'index',
],
```

Comment: Seriously, `actionCreate` instead of `actionIndex` works

Comment: Glad it works. I guess the reason it works like this is that usually `POST` data is trying to create something, whatever that may be, so that it the default setting. You should be able to override that setting though if it doesn't suit your use-case